# How to implement multiple field validation at my Login page(JSF 2.0)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I need a multiple field validation for  login page (many fields validated at once in the same method). I don't know how to implement it correctly. I am following an example I found at: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html

I get a bit confused in the JSF part.Can somebody give me a hand, what am I missing?

The page:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel>
        <h:outputText value="*Em@il:" />
        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{securityController.email}"
            required="true" />
        <br />
        <h:outputText value="*Password: " />
        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{securityController.password}"
            required="true">
            <f:validator validatorId="loginValidator" />
        </h:inputSecret>
        <br />
        <span style="color: red;"><h:message for="password"
                showDetail="true" /></span>
        <br />
        <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{securityController.logIn()}" />
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

This is the managed bean with the validate method:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SecurityController implements Validator {

    @EJB
    private IAuthentificationEJB authentificationEJB;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String notificationValue;

    public String logIn() {
        if (authentificationEJB.saveUserState(email, password)) {
            notificationValue = "Dobro dosli";
            return "main.xhtml";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent validate,
            Object value) {
        String emailInput = (String) value;
        String emailPatternText = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)"
            + "*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        Pattern emailPattern = null;
        Matcher emailMatcher = null;
        emailPattern = Pattern.compile(emailPatternText);
        emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(emailInput);
        String inputFromField = (String) value;
        String alphanumericPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
        Pattern passwordPattern = null;
        Matcher passwordMatcher = null;
        passwordPattern = Pattern.compile(alphanumericPattern);
        passwordMatcher = passwordPattern.matcher(inputFromField);
        if (!emailMatcher.matches() && !passwordMatcher.matches()) {
            if (authentificationEJB.checkCredentials(email, password) == false) {
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                    "Pogresan email ili lozinka");
                throw new ValidatorException(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getNotificationValue() {
        return notificationValue;
    }

    public void setNotificationValue(String notificationValue) {
        this.notificationValue = notificationValue;
    }
}
```

EJB that interacts with database to check credentials:

```
@Stateful(name = "ejbs/AuthentificationEJB")
public class AuthentificationEJB implements IAuthentificationEJB {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    // Login
    public boolean saveUserState(String email, String password) {
        // 1-Send query to database to see if that user exist
        Query query = em
            .createQuery("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.email=:emailparam "
                + "AND r.password=:passwordparam");
        query.setParameter("emailparam", email);
        query.setParameter("passwordparam", password);
        // 2-If the query returns the user(Role) object, store it somewhere in
        // the session
        Role role = (Role) query.getSingleResult();
        if (role != null && role.getEmail().equals(email)
            && role.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getSessionMap().put("userRole", role);
            // 3-return true if the user state was saved
            System.out.println(role.getEmail() + role.getPassword());
            return true;
        }
        // 4-return false otherwise
        System.out.println(role.getEmail() + role.getPassword());
        return false;
    }

    // Logout
    public void releaseUserState() {
        // 1-Check if there is something saved in the session(or wherever the
        // state is saved)
        if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getSessionMap().isEmpty()) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().release();
        }
        // 2-If 1 then flush it
    }

    // Check if user is logged in
    public boolean checkAuthentificationStatus() {
        // 1-Check if there is something saved in the session(This means the
        // user is logged in)
        if ((FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getSessionMap().get("userRole") != null)) {
            // 2-If there is not a user already loged, then return false
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkCredentials(String email, String password) {
        Query checkEmailExists = em
            .createQuery("SELECT COUNT(r.email) FROM Role r WHERE "
                + "r.email=:emailparam AND r.password=:passwordparam");
        checkEmailExists.setParameter("emailparam", email);
        checkEmailExists.setParameter("passwordparam", password);
        long matchCounter = 0;
        matchCounter = (Long) checkEmailExists.getSingleResult();
        if (matchCounter > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Update**

Removed LoginValidator

The modified managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SecurityController {

    @EJB
    private IAuthentificationEJB authentificationEJB;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String notificationValue;

    public String logIn() {
        if (authentificationEJB.saveUserState(email, password)) {
            notificationValue = "Dobro dosli";
            return "main.xhtml";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        UIInput emailComponent = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get(
            "emailComponent");
        String email = "";
        String password = "";
        email = (String) emailComponent.getValue();
        password = (String) value;
        String emailInput = email;
        String emailPatternText = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)"
            + "*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        Pattern emailPattern = null;
        Matcher emailMatcher = null;
        emailPattern = Pattern.compile(emailPatternText);
        emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(emailInput);
        String passwordInput = password;
        String alphanumericPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
        Pattern passwordPattern = null;
        Matcher passwordMatcher = null;
        passwordPattern = Pattern.compile(alphanumericPattern);
        passwordMatcher = passwordPattern.matcher(passwordInput);
        if (!emailMatcher.matches() && !passwordMatcher.matches()) {
            if (authentificationEJB.checkCredentials(emailInput, passwordInput) == false) {
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                    "Pogresan email ili lozinka");
                throw new ValidatorException(msg);
            }
        }
        if (emailInput == null || passwordInput == null) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Zaboraviliste nesto");
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
        if (passwordInput.length() <= 0 || emailInput.length() <= 0) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Zaboraviliste nesto");
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }
    // Get set methods
}
```

The login form:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel>
        <h:outputText value="*Em@il:" />
        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{securityController.email}"
            binding="#{emailComponent}" />
        <br />
        <h:outputText value="*Password: " />
        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{securityController.password}"
            validator="#{securityController.validate}">
            <f:attribute name="emailComponent" value="#{emailComponent}" />
        </h:inputSecret>
        <br />
        <span style="color: red;"><h:message for="password"
                showDetail="true" /></span>
        <br />
        <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{securityController.logIn()}" />
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Modified The saveUserState() method at the EJB:

```
// Login
public boolean saveUserState(String email, String password) {
    // 1-Send query to database to see if that user exist
    Query query = em
        .createQuery("SELECT r FROM Role r WHERE r.email=:emailparam "
            + "AND r.password=:passwordparam");
    query.setParameter("emailparam", email);
    query.setParameter("passwordparam", password);
    // 2-If the query returns the user(Role) object, store it somewhere in
    // the session
    try {
        Role role = (Role) query.getSingleResult();
        if (role != null && role.getEmail().equals(email)
            && role.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getSessionMap().put("userRole", role);
            // 3-return true if the user state was saved
            System.out.println(role.getEmail() + role.getPassword());
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // This fix the bug that does not display the message when wrong
        // password!
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Pogresan email ili lozinka");
        throw new ValidatorException(msg);
    }
    // 4-return false otherwise
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the first component by `binding` and pass it as attribute of the component you're validating. You also need to use `validator` attribute of the input field instead of `<f:validator>` when you want to call a validator method inside a managed bean. Finally you should get rid of the `implements Validator` on the bean class.

```
<h:outputText value="*Em@il:" />
<h:inputText id="email" binding="#{emailComponent}" value="#{securityController.email}" required="true"/>                   
<br/>
<h:outputText value="*Password: " />
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{securityController.password}" validator="#{securityController.validateEmailAndPassword}" required="true">
    <f:attribute name="emailComponent" value="#{emailComponent}" />
</h:inputSecret>
```

with

```
public void validateEmailAndPassword(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    UIInput emailComponent = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("emailComponent");
    String email = (String) emailComponent.getValue();
    String password = (String) value;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I added the LoginValidator as an standalone class not a managed bean, and i removed the validation method from the managed bean. I get a NullPointerException at the LoginValidator where it says:String password = (String) value; Why is that? is it ok that i injected the EJB in this class too?

Comment: That line can impossibly throw a NPE. Isn't it another line or did you mean that the value is `null`? If the latter, just add a `if (password != null)` check before accessing/manipulating it.

Comment: Sorry it is line 27 that throws NPE: 
String email = emailComponent.getValue().toString();

Comment: Then the `emailComponent` is `null`. Did you bind it properly by `binding="#{emailComponent}"` ?

Comment: No i didn't i forgot it. I just added the binding. It works fine now butonly when i give a correct credentials, when credentials are wrong ore the email field is empty i get NPE

Comment: Oh, you should not use `toString()`. This will fail if `getValue()` returns `null`. You should use `(String)` cast. I fixed the answer.

Comment: I did do (String) cast instead of toString but still get NPE at line 46:
if (authentificationEJB.checkCredentials(emailInput, passwordInput) == false)  

This has something to do with the EJB. LoginValidator is not a ManagedBean does that affect?

Comment: Ah right, I overlooked the EJB requirement. You cannot inject EJB in a validator. Put the `validate()` method in a managed bean instead and use `validator="#{bean.validate}"` instead of `<f:validator>`, but **do not** let the bean implement `Validator`. I updated the answer. PS: please don't say that you're getting NPE's, this is not specific enough, just say what exactly is null (which is `authentificationEJB` in this case).

Comment: I did that(updated the code) there is no LoginValidator class and it is done in the managedBean. Now i see the validation messages when i leave empty fields and add wrong email formats, but when the credentials are wrong, i get this exception at the authentificationEJB:
SEVERE: javax.ejb.EJBException
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException......
Caused by: javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.

Comment: That's a different problem. Did you read the caused by message? There's just no single match, i.e. the email is valid :) Put it in a try-catch or just check `getResultList().isEmpty()` instead.

Comment: I did a try catch and now i don't see that exception. The problem is fixed Thanks. P.S the only little bug i have is that i dont see the validation message when the password is entered wrong.

Comment: You need to throw a `ValidatorException` when password is wrong. It'll end up in `<h:message>`.

Comment: I just did that but the error ends up in my browser as HTTP error 500:
javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException: Pogresan email ili lozinka

What i did was add the throw at the catch inside the EJB(see update) Why is not displayed as validation message?